# Camel Route onExcpetion/errorHandle not catching Salesforce Compotent Exception

Tags: groovy, apache-camel

First time using Camel Routes, all the Apache docs and the info around sof make it look very easy....  (this is in groovy, using Apache Camel and the Camel Salesforce components as libs)

```
 class SFRouteClass extends RouteBuilder {

   @Override
    void configure() {
        def camelRouteId

        from("direct:moveFailedMessage")
            .process { Exchange exchange ->
                exchange.out
            } 
        from('direct:sfe')
            .onException(Exception.class)
                .to('log:sfe?level=INFO&showHeaders=true&multiline=true')
                .to('direct:moveFailedMessage')
                .maximumRedeliveries(0)
            .end()
            .routeId('sfe')
            .enrich('direct:salesforceCheckLeadByIDUserHashId'.toString(), new AggregationStrategy() { ..... }
 } 

org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.api.SalesforceException: Error {404:Not Found} executing {GET:https://.....}
    at org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.internal.client.AbstractClientBase$1.onComplete(AbstractClientBase.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.responseSuccess(HttpReceiver.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.messageComplete(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseContent(HttpParser.java:1487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.parse(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.process(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.receive(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.receive(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onFillable(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.api.SalesforceException: {errors:[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}],statusCode:404}
    at org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.internal.client.DefaultRestClient.createRestException(DefaultRestClient.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.component.salesforce.internal.client.AbstractClientBase$1.onComplete(AbstractClientBase.java:175)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

This works if there is no error.  My problem is the onException never triggers. I have tried to make a global errorHandler to the config, and I have tried to make a global onExcpetion.  Nothing catches the error and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either

1. set no error handler on the route that starts at `direct:salesforceCheckLeadByIDUserHashId` so the route scoped error handler you have on the other route can kick in
2. Or add / move that onException to that route as well.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the other class had the route in it that was the called one... I have to handle it there first  > . <

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the doTry / doCatch way ?

```
from('direct:sfe')
   .routeId('sfe')
    .doTry()
    .enrich('direct:salesforceCheckLeadByIDUserHashId'.toString(), new AggregationStrategy() { ..... }
    .doCatch(Exception.class)
              .to('log:sfe?level=INFO&showHeaders=true&multiline=true')
              .to('direct:moveFailedMessage')
              .maximumRedeliveries(0) // NOt needed as default is 0
      .end()
```

Comment: tried but it turns out my error was I have to handle it in the direct:salesforceCheckLeadByIDUserHashId first.  Thanks though will keep that pattern in mind.